# Meteor-react Admin Setup

Tags: meteor, reactjs, authentication, passwords, admin

I would like to build an admin authentication using `react` and `meteor` I've set up the following log-in form using `React` inside the client folder:

```
class Admin extends Component {

  onSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const self = this;
    const email = $(event.target).find('[name=email]').val();
    const password = $(event.target).find('[name=password]').val();

    Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password, function (err) {
      if (err) console.log(err.reason);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='flex-login'>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <div className='login'>
            <div className='welcome'>
              <p><strong>Greetings</strong>, my dear master :)  </p>
              <p>Did anything surprise you today?</p>
            </div>
            <input name='email' type="email" placeholder="Name" />
            <input name='password' type="password" placeholder="Secretword" />
            <button type="submit">Enter</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And have added the following Accounts.createUser into the server main.js file:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Accounts } from 'meteor/accounts-base';

// Creating user
Meteor.startup(() => {
  if (Meteor.users.find().count === 0) {
    Accounts.createUser({
      email: 'master@mail.com',
      password: 'master'
    });
  }
});
```

When I try to login using defined account information I receive console.log `User not found`.

Can you please explain what I am missing in order to achieve the result?

I will do also appreciate a lot if you could explain me or point me to some external resources how can should a custom secure login for administrator in order to make it save in `production version`.
The purpose of these authentication is to allow further access of managing collections' information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using count instead of count() in Meteor.users.find().count()

Comment: You are right, that was a problem. Now it works, thank you a lot. Can you please explain is it save to have admin account information on server side of meteor app in production version?

Comment: I couldnot understand what do you mean.Would you please explain what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I would like to build custom admin panel, so the I need to define admin account somehow to make the further authentication and verification on admin-pages using Meteor.userID();

Answer (score 0):

I think the admin is not being created since there are other users the value of `Meteor.users.find().count()` is never going to be zero. You should rather check if the users with role 'admin' is zero and create the admin. You can use the role package here [alanning:roles](https://atmospherejs.com/alanning/roles) to add role to the users.

Hope it helps

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion khem, actually when I type into the console Meteor.users.find().count() I recieve 0 :)

Comment: use count() its a method you are using count in meteor.users.find().count()